# How to create a new branch in a local repository taking code from a remote branch without doing any merging

Tags: git, github

I've a branch on a remote repository and i want to bring that branch locally so i can do a rebase. 
I've added the repo of the remote branch which is called github. If i do

```
git checkout -b feature/AIOEC-168
git pull github feature/AIOEC-168
```

a merge occur. I would like to copy feature/AIOEC-168 locally and then on that branch do `git rebase develop`, how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `git pull` try [`git fetch`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html):

```
git fetch github
git rebase github/feature/AIOEC-168
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a local version of the remote branch that also sets the remote's branch as upstream, use `git checkout`'s `--track` flag:

```
git checkout --track github/feature/AIOEC-168
```

That will create `feature/AIOEC-168` locally, it'll be identical to the `github` remote's version (and will also set up that version as the upstream tracking branch), and you can rebase from there with any rebase command you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

On any halfway-recent version of git, you can just `git checkout feature/AIOEC-168`, which will detect the similarly-named branch in `origin` and create a local branch of the same name, tracking the `origin` branch.